# how to set partial nodes as same rank in graphviz with python

Tags: graphviz

source code

```
digraph G {
        node_18 [label=2 color=BLACK fontcolor=BLACK]
        node_19 [label=1 color=BLACK fontcolor=BLACK]
        node_18 -> node_19
        node_20 [label=4 color=RED fontcolor=RED]
        node_18 -> node_20
        node_21 [label=3 color=BLACK fontcolor=BLACK]
        node_20 -> node_21
        node_22 [label=5 color=BLACK fontcolor=BLACK]
        node_20 -> node_22
        node_23 [label=-1 color=BLACK fontcolor=BLACK style=invis]
        node_22 -> node_23 [style=invis]
        node_24 [label=6 color=RED fontcolor=RED]
        node_22 -> node_24
        label="step6---add 6 succeed"
        node_19 -> node_20 [style=invis]
        node_21 -> node_22 [style=invis]
        node_23 -> node_24 [style=invis]

        {rank=same; node_19;node_20}
        {rank=same; node_21;node_22}
        {rank=same; node_23;node_24}
}
```

The last 3 lines("{rank=same ...") are added manually, can I add them with python graphviz?

I have searched the solution from google, but the solution is to make them in the same subgraph.

But they should not be in the subgraph. How to achieve this?

Comment: Go ahead and put them in a subgraph. To Graphviz, a subgraph is just a set of nodes with some common feature - like rank, or shape or width or font.  A node can be included in many subgraphs. (A cluster subgraph is something else entirely.)

Comment: Because they are already in a subgraph, the entire file consists of many subgraphs.

I picked a subgraph to illustrate.

Comment: But even in your example you put them in a subgraph. `{ ... }` is an unnamed subgraph syntax ([docs](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html))

Comment: I have solved it.

A subgraph can also contain other subgraphs.